# Handle to window handle

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I've tried using the "grab all of the process IDs enumerated by the desktop" method, however that doesn't work.

- Is there a way to convert a handle to a window handle? -or-
- Is there a way to take a process ID and find out all of the child windows spawned by the process?

I don't want to use `FindWindow` due to multiple process issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could call [EnumWindows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx) to iterate over all the top-level windows on the screen, then use [GetWindowThreadProcessId()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find out which ones belong to your process.

For example, something like:

```
BOOL CALLBACK ForEachTopLevelWindow(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lp)
{
    DWORD processId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processId);
    if (processId == (DWORD) lp) {
        // `hwnd` belongs to the target process.
    }
    return TRUE;
}

VOID LookupProcessWindows(DWORD processId)
{
    EnumWindows(ForEachTopLevelWindow, (LPARAM) processId);
}
```