# How do I call a windows dll function from cygwin python?

Tags: python, windows, dll, cygwin, ctypes

I have a `Windows` `python3.7` function which successfully calls the `kernel32.dll` `GetSystemPowerStatus` function using `ctypes` to interrogate the power status to see if my laptop is on AC or battery power. This is a pure python solution.

I want to port this function to `cygwin` `python3.7`. Out of the box, `python3` for `cygwin`'s `ctypes` does not seem to allow calling a windows dll. I would prefer a pure python solution, but I can use C/C++ if necessary. Does anyone have an example of how to do this?

Edited to add the code (lines 63-67) and error messages:

```
elif _os.name == 'posix' and _sys.platform == 'cygwin':
    # c:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
    kernel32_name = '/proc/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/kernel32.dll'
    kernel32 = CDLL(kernel32_name)
    _GetSystemPowerStatus = kernel32.GetSystemPowerStatus


$ python3.7 GetSystemPowerStatus.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GetSystemPowerStatus.py", line 82, in <module>
    result, systemPowerStatus = GetSystemPowerStatus()
  File "GetSystemPowerStatus.py", line 66, in GetSystemPowerStatus
    kernel32 = CDLL(kernel32_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: Invalid argument
```

python2.7 gives the same error, but at line 366.

Solved. See my own answer below.

Comment: Please give the error message that you get when you run your working windows code inside cygwin

Comment: '$ python3.7 GetSystemPowerStatus.py⏎
Traceback (most recent call last):⏎
  File "GetSystemPowerStatus.py", line 69, in <module>⏎
    result, systemPowerStatus = GetSystemPowerStatus()⏎
  File "GetSystemPowerStatus.py", line 57, in GetSystemPowerStatus⏎
    _GetSystemPowerStatus = cdll.kernel32.GetSystemPowerStatus⏎
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 426, in __getattr__⏎
    dll = self._dlltype(name)⏎
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__⏎
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)⏎
OSError: No such file or directory⏎'

Comment: Edit the question with additional, formatted information.  Comments obviously are a mess to read.

Comment: Quite puzzling, actually this works for me: `ctypes.CDLL("/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/user32.dll")` but not with `kernel32.dll`. I get exactly the same error. So it's possible to load a windows library from cygwin, but **not** kernel32 :(

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting. Must dig in source of ctypes, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As you I wasn't able to get `kernel32.dll` (although it works with other DLLs like `user32`, `msvcrt`, `kernelbase`, etc.)

I found a pretty contrived way of doing it... This uses kernelbase.dll (which exports `GetModuleHandle`) to get an handle on `kernel32.dll`, then call `CDLL` with the handle optional keyword:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import ctypes

def main():
    # the idea is to load kernelbase.dll which will allow us to call GetModuleHandleW() on kernel32.dll
    try:
        kernel_base = ctypes.CDLL("/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/kernelbase.dll")
    except OSError:
        print("Can't load kernelbase.dll...")
        return -1

    gmhw = kernel_base.GetModuleHandleW
    gmhw.argtypes = (ctypes.c_wchar_p, )
    gmhw.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

    # call GetModuleHandleW on kernel32.dll (which is loaded by default in the Python process)
    kernel32_base_addr = gmhw("kernel32.dll")
    print(f"Got kernel32 base address: {kernel32_base_addr:#x}")

    # now call CDLL with optional arguments
    kernel32 = ctypes.CDLL("/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/kernel32.dll", handle=kernel32_base_addr, use_last_error=True)

    # test with GetSystemPowerStatus
    print(f"GetSystemPowerStatus: {kernel32.GetSystemPowerStatus}")

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit convoluted. I found a better way.

Answer (score -1):

After finding that I could load `user32.dll` easily, I did some more investigation with the source and `pdb` and `ldd`. What follows is my solution.

```
elif _os.name == 'posix' and _sys.platform == 'cygwin':
    RTLD_LOCAL = 0  # from /usr/include/dlfcn.h
    RTLD_LAZY = 1
    RTLD_NOW = 2
    RTLD_GLOBAL = 4
    RTLD_NODELETE = 8
    RTLD_NOLOAD = 16
    RTLD_DEEPBIND = 32
    kernel32_name = '/proc/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/kernel32.dll'
    kernel32 = CDLL(kernel32_name, mode=RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_NOLOAD)
    _GetSystemPowerStatus = kernel32.GetSystemPowerStatus
```

The common code to call the function is:

```
_GetSystemPowerStatus.restype = c_bool
_GetSystemPowerStatus.argtypes = [c_void_p,]

_systemPowerStatus = _SystemPowerStatus()  # not shown, see ctypes module doc

result = _GetSystemPowerStatus(byref(_systemPowerStatus))

return result, SystemPowerStatus(_systemPowerStatus)
```

This works fine with Python 2.7, 3.6 and 3.6 on

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 host 3.0.1(0.338/5/3) 2019-02-20 10:19 x86_64 Cygwin
```

Thanks to all for their help.

Comment: Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781370/is-there-an-alternative-way-to-import-ctypes-wintypes-in-cygwin.